Not able to pull dynamics contents in power automate for PO record from Dynamics F&O
Below the brief history of the task.
When PO is created/reviewed (marked as completed not approved through internal dynamics workflow) we want to trigger a Power Automate flow upon marking as the PO complete. Power Automate flow should sent out an email with approve /reject button and having the Product line items details in the email.
Once the record is Approved/Rejected through email, it should update back the Purchase order back Dynamics.
Currently challenge which we are facing is we are not able to get all the dynamics variable in power automate to pull PO related details in the email.
We tried to update the Schema of "Purchase order confirmed" to power automate, but we are not getting all the required fields from PO. We do need to pull the PO and product line items related details, like Vendor name, Product name, cost, unit qty., etc. And then we need to club this all info in the email which will be shoot out to higher management for approval of the PO. They should have Approve and Reject button in email itself.
Management should approve record through email itself and once approved, it should go back and approve the PO record in Dynamics-365 F&O
